# How to enable push notifications of emails?

Tags: iphone, mail.app, notifications, apns

A quick question with perhaps no answer,

How can I enable push notifications of emails?

What currently happens when I get an email is that my phone vibrates or rings, then I look at the locked screen and no information is displayed.

I'd like a preview of the email in a notification window with at least the sender.

I currently have 3 mailboxes, one in google, one in hotmail, the other a private work exchange server.

Is there a solution to receive push notifications for all of my mailboxes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're talking about the notification settings for Mail, not whether push is on. To see new mail messages in the Lock Screen:

Settings > Notifications > Mail > Make sure "View in Lock Screen" is turned ON.

If you're concerned about your mail's push settings, those are in:

Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendar > Fetch New Data > Make sure "Push" is set how you want it.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 11+ users, find Push Mail’s Parameters by going to Settings > Accounts & Passwords > Fetch New Data.

Comment: The OPs question was about Notifications and not Push settings.  How does this answer address Notifications?

Answer (score -3):

There is no push for mail settings for iPhone 5

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Also, this is in direct contradiction to the currently provided information in the other answer (and my own knowledge); could you expand on what makes you say this?